# logic issue while setting condition

Tags: c#

I got a comment like this

This check (`if (rp != null)`) should not be here.  The variable `irp.ResourcePolicy` should be set to `null` when rp is `null` because the Resource Policy is unknown.  Otherwise the previous value will be used and the previous value might be incorrect.

```
// Search for the specified resource policy
                                ResourcePolicy rp = null;
                                try
                                {
                                    int rpindex = allObjects.Find(new Guid(policyGuid));
                                    if (rpindex != -1)
                                    {
                                        rp = (ResourcePolicy)allObjects.GetAt(rpindex);
                                    }
                                }
                                catch (System.Exception err)
                                {
                                    SpoDebug.DebugTraceSevere(func, "Bad GUID: " + policyGuid + "  Exception: " + err.Message);
                                    rp = null;
                                }

                                if (rp == null)
                                {
                                    SpoDebug.DebugTraceSevere(func, "Unable to find ResourcePolicy with GUID: " + policyGuid);
                                }

                                // Search for the specified host   


foreach (DataModelObject dmo in allObjects)
{
    if (dmo is IResourcePolicy && string.Compare(dmo.Name, hostName, true) == 0)
    {
        IResourcePolicy irp = (IResourcePolicy)dmo;
        irp.AgentVersion = agentVersion;
        if (rp != null)  // this is the condition we need to look
        {
            irp.ResourcePolicy = rp;
            irp.AgentPolicyVersion.Version = Convert.ToInt64(policyVersion);
            irp.ResourcePolicyEnabled = Convert.ToBoolean(enabled);
        }
        // Distribute the object without saving it.
        SpoServer.Spurt.ServerSendObject(dmo, true, 0);

        break;
   }

}
```

So I made it this way:

```
foreach (DataModelObject dmo in allObjects)
{
    if (dmo is IResourcePolicy && string.Compare(dmo.Name, hostName, true) == 0)
    {
        IResourcePolicy irp = (IResourcePolicy)dmo;
        irp.AgentVersion = agentVersion;
        if (rp == null)
        {
            irp.ResourcePolicy = null;
        }
        else
        {
            irp.ResourcePolicy = rp;
            irp.AgentPolicyVersion.Version = Convert.ToInt64(policyVersion);
            irp.ResourcePolicyEnabled = Convert.ToBoolean(enabled);
        }

        // Distribute the object without saving it.
        SpoServer.Spurt.ServerSendObject(dmo, true, 0);

        break;
    }
}
```

Is that sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

Looks ok to me - although `irp.ResourcePolicy = rp;` is going to be true in all cases, so you could probably move that out of the condition block (although by having it in a block you are making it more obvious to the casual reader).

Answer (score 1):

What do you want `irp.AgentPolicyVersion.Version` and `irp.ResourcePolicyEnabled` to be when `rp` is null? I would expect them to be set to some appropriate default values rather than left as they are.

Otherwise, I would have written it like this:

```
IResourcePolicy irp = (IResourcePolicy)dmo;
irp.AgentVersion = agentVersion;
irp.ResourcePolicy = rp;
if (rp != null)
{
    irp.AgentPolicyVersion.Version = Convert.ToInt64(policyVersion);
    irp.ResourcePolicyEnabled = Convert.ToBoolean(enabled);
}
```

Comment: i changed the question little bit,,means added

Comment: What you mean by default value,,Is it set to Null

Comment: @peter: Well, your question suggests that irp.ResourcePolicy might already have a value... so I would assume that irp.ResourcePolicyEnabled and irp.AgentPolicyVersion.Version might as well. I would expect you'd want to reset those to something like false and 0 if rp is null.